# Siri : IntentHandler not behaving correctly with device Touch ID

Tags: payment, ios10, sirikit

What is the right approach to handle device `LocalAuthentication` with `NSIntent`? Currently it is not showing payment sent pop up in Siri `INSendPaymentIntent`.

```
- (void)handleSendPayment:(INSendPaymentIntent *)intent
           completion:(void (^)(INSendPaymentIntentResponse *response))completion {

        __block INSendPaymentIntentResponse *siriResponse;

        LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
        NSError *error = nil;

        // Check if device supports TouchID
        if ([context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error]) {

            // TouchID supported, show it to user
            [context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics

                    localizedReason:@"Unlock using Touch ID to transaction”
                              reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

                                  if (success) {
                                      // This action has to be on main thread and must be synchronous
                                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                        //  Payment handling code goes here
                                      });
                                  }
                                  else if (error) {
                                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                          siriResponse = [[INSendPaymentIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INSendPaymentIntentResponseCodeSuccess userActivity:nil];
                                      });
                                  }
                              }];
        }
}
```

If I remove Local Authentication payment works just fine!!

Comment: Hello Pratik, Did you resolve this issue.Please let me know. I am also going through same phone.

Comment: Indeed experiencing the same behaviour when payment is initiated before the device is unlocked. When device is unlocked before calling Siri, the confirmation shows up.

Comment: @Kashif still not!!

Comment: @PratikGoswami Yups still not, by the way, in our app, when user Intent showing confirmation for payment, it navigate to that specific screen for that user.