# Increasing security for payment with Sirikit

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

I'm trying to increase security for my payments app which is integrated with Siri.
I used Apple's sample code from this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/IntentHandling/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017335-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) , and I adjusted the following in order to implement touch ID authentication before performing the payment:
(Added function "authenticate" for touch ID authentication, and called it in the handle function)

```
 func handle(sendPayment intent: INSendPaymentIntent, completion: @escaping (INSendPaymentIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    self.authenticate(successAuth: {

        guard let payee = intent.payee,
            let payeeHandle = payee.personHandle,
            let currencyAmount = intent.currencyAmount,
            let amount = currencyAmount.amount,
            let currencyCode = currencyAmount.currencyCode
            else {
                completion(INSendPaymentIntentResponse(code: .failure, userActivity: nil))
                return
        }

        self.contactLookup.lookup(emailAddress: payeeHandle.value) { contact in
            guard let contact = contact else {
                completion(INSendPaymentIntentResponse(code: .failure, userActivity: nil))
                return
            }

            let payment = Payment(contact: contact, amount: amount, currencyCode: currencyCode)

            self.paymentProvider.send(payment) { success, _, _ in
                guard success else {
                    completion(INSendPaymentIntentResponse(code: .failure, userActivity: nil))
                    return
                }

                let response = INSendPaymentIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: nil)
                response.paymentRecord = self.makePaymentRecord(for: intent)

                completion(response)
            }
        }
        }) { (error) in
            print("error in authentication")
            completion(INSendPaymentIntentResponse(code: .failure, userActivity: nil))
            return
    }

}

func authenticate(successAuth: @escaping () -> Void, failure: @escaping (NSError?) -> Void) {
    // 1. Create a authentication context
    let authenticationContext = LAContext()
    var error:NSError?
    guard authenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) else {
        failure(error)
        return
    }
    // 3. Check the fingerprint
    authenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(
        .deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,
        localizedReason: "Unlock to send the money",
        reply: { [unowned self] (success, error) -> Void in

            if( success ) {
                successAuth()

            }else {
                let message = self.errorMessageForLAErrorCode(errorCode: (error! as NSError).code)
                print(message)
                failure(error! as NSError)
            }

        })
    successAuth()
}
```

The problem is Siri says: " Sorry, you'll need to continue in the app"

Comment: I think you are facing same problem as me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686056/siri-intenthandler-not-behaving-correctly-with-device-touch-id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After careful debugging, I found out that the problem occurred only when Siri suggests last payee or last currency amount, so I commented these parts in resolvePayee and resolveCurrencyAmount, and the flow worked perfectly! After confirming the payment, it asks for the touch ID authentication and then sends the payment. Thanks guys!

Comment: What you mean by "Siri suggests last payee or last currency amount"?